# Is otx (Object Tool Extended) still actively being maintained for reverse engineering legacy OS X binaries?

Tags: apple-macintosh, disassembly, reverse-engineering

otx is a tool used to disassemble Mach-O binaries on OS X 10.0-10.4.  It is an enhancement on top of otool to add additional symbol information to its disassembled output.

The main site and SVN repository (http://otx.osxninja.com/) appears to be long dead.  Is there a new maintainer (official or unofficial) or someone hosting the code to disassemble Mach-O binaries on legacy macOS systems?

I posted a similar question on Reverse Enginerring Stack Exchange ([Is there an up to date fork of otx?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/14038/17972)), but it did not generate any activity.  To keep this question in-scope, I will only focus on the older versions of OS X, but I am also interested in a version of otx that works on any OS X version.

Comment: We can only prove the positive, not the negative. So the easiest way to answer this would be to create one.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I could fork it myself, but I don't have the original source.  I guess this is a question to see if anyone knows of a fork that is still actively being maintained or has been updated in the past few years or so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, the most up to date modern fork of otx is being maintained by Zhi-Wei Cai on GitHub [here](https://github.com/x43x61x69/otx).  v1.7: Build 566 or a fresh clone of master should work on any modern OS X system.

But that's not why we're here.  This is Retrocomputing Stack Exchange after all.  The most recent fork of otx which works on legacy OS X platforms is probably the [linuxaged fork](https://github.com/linuxaged/otx).  I also realized an [archive of the original svn server](http://web.archive.org/web/20130829145110/http://otx.osxninja.com/builds/trunk/) is available on the Wayback Machine.  This provides otx 0.16b which works for reverse engineering PowerPC binaries.